# RMI, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rmi

under Netbeans ,I created a project containing an interface "i_object" This interface represents the remote object "impl_i_object" and "impl_i_object" implements all the interface method.
one main class to the client  "Main_client"  and one for the server "Main_server" ...
when I start the server and the client  its work smoothly.

[image]

But when I separated from my project into two projects (client and server) look at the screenshot:

[image]

here, when I run the server it works but when I run the client it display this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server.i_object (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
at client.Main_client.main(Main_client.java:24)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server.i_object (no security manager:  RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:554)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:646)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:311)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:257)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1549)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1511)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
... 3 more
    Java Result: 1
```

what's the problem ?

Comment: You try to use client.i_object instead of server.i_object. Also, please read Java coding convensions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says :

> no security manager:  RMI class loader disabled

RMI requires a security manager to run.

Example:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/459111/java/java/no-security-manager-rmi-class

**UPDATE:**
This [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/rmi/RMISecurityManager.html) talks about the security in RMI

Comment: thanks, but it works when I put them in the same project without the security manager, you can explain please?

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi A security manager is required only when you seperate the client from the server.

Comment: -1. RMI does *not* require a security manager to run *at all.* It requires a security manager if and only if you want to use the codebase feature.

Comment: @EJP Seriously, do you read the comments before you vote? I already said in the comment right above yours "A security manager is required only when you seperate the client from the server" which is exactly what you are saying...

Comment: @AdelBoutros Do you read the comments before you comment? It *isn't* exactly what I said at all. What I said is perfectly clear, and I will now repeat it. You only need a security manager if you want to use the codebase feature. You don't have to use the codebase feature, even when you 'separate the client from the server'.

Comment: @EJP Quoting from oracle: _A codebase can be defined as a source, or a place, from which to load classes into a Java virtual machine_ When you seperate the client and the server code. Then you need to define a codebase in order to know where the code lies.

Comment: @AdelBoutros That is now the fourth mistake you have made on this topic. The codebase feature refers to the system property `java.rmi.server.codebase`. If you make the remote interface class and its closure available to the client in its CLASSPATH, and to the Registry, you don't have to use the codebase feature, contrary to what you have claimed here. I have dozens of such RMI deployments with separate clients and servers and no security managers. Any one of these is a sufficient counterexample. Clearly you don't know very much about it.

Comment: @EJP I am telling you what I learned. Anyway, all what matters is that my answer was useful for the asker

Comment: @AdelBoutros Have a look at the RMI Specification, ##3.4 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch5.html and 5.6 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-server27.html, where you will learn the truth of the matter. It's hard to see how a wrong answer can have been of any use to anyone; in any case that is most certainly not all that matters.

Comment: @EJP agreed that server manager is not required if we are not using Codebase and jars / classes are available in classpath. BUT in the above case what could be the solution please ? Perhaps I will post a separate question with the issue I am encountering ..

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was making a copy of the interface in a package with the same package name in each project server and client